# Can a CFI whose instrument rating isn't valid legally offer instrument instruction?

Tags: flight-training

Can a flight instructor whose instrument rating isn't valid legally offer instrument instruction?

Comment: Not valid as in revoked/limited or not valid as in, not current for IFR operations [(does not meet FAR61.3](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.3)) depending on interpretation the answers may vary quite a bit.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! For questions about regulations, please always tell us which country you're asking about. The [tour] may be helpful if you're new to StackExchange.

Comment: Ground or flight? In IMC or in VMC?

Answer (score 3):

if a CFII is not IFR current, they can still offer training on a simulator, or offer training in IFR simulated conditions (e.g. hood time) while the CFII is flying in VFR conditions

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide instrument instruction, the instructor must hold a CFI Instrument, or CFII. They must also be Instrument current in order to file/fly under IFR.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here

Instrument currency - Per 61.56(c), you must be Instrument current to serve as PIC aboard an IFR flight or one below VFR weather minimums.

For a pilot receiving instruction to meet the aeronautical experience requirements for an instrument rating (61.65), the flight instructor is considered PIC for all dual training flights conducted under IFR or weather below VFR minimums (1.1).  Therefor for all dual IFR training flights, the instructor must be instrument current to serve as PIC

Now an certified instrument instructor may administer training to meet the aeronautical experience requirements for an instrument rating.  But this not need be done in IFR.  An instructor can provide this training in a sim, FTD, or on a dual instruction flight conducted under VFR.  In these circumstances, the CFII need not be instrument current to administer the instruction and the student can log that time toward an instrument rating.

So flor local VFR training flight with the student under the hood, this is fine.  But if the flight is say filed as IFR, then the CFII must be instrument current to conduct the training.